# Change Add to Cart text on hover

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

Is it possible to change the `Add to cart` button in Woocommerce to "Select size", for example, if a customer has yet to choose an (required) option. Then, change it back to "add to cart" once the option is selected?

The Website of manolo blahnik has this feature, and I find it's a good UX for customers. On their website, the first stage is "Add to cart".
If someone hovers over the button, but hasn't chosen their option, it displays "Please select a size".
But if someone has choosen an option, it stays as "Add to cart".

On Mobile, because there is no hover like on pc, it always shows "Please select a size" until the option is chosen, then it changes to "Add to cart".

I'm wondering if it is  possible to do this with woocommerce.

[image: Example]

Comment: Sure, it's possible. You could add a "hover" event on the button using JS and do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mouseover` and `mouseout` event handlers on the `Add to cart` button. The following code snippet demonstrates the functionality.

On `mouseover` of the button, the values of the `required` form fields are checked and the button `text` and `title` are amended using the `data-warn` attribute of the form field.

On `mouseout` the button `text` and `title` are reset using the content of the `data-title` attribute on the button.

```js
// handle to button
var addToCartBtn = document.getElementById('add-to-cart-button');
// 'mouseover' event handler
addToCartBtn.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
  // get all form elements
  var inputs = this.form.elements;
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // find the first empty required field
    if (inputs[i].required && inputs[i].value == '') {
      // set the button's mouse over text
      event.target.title = inputs[i].dataset.warn;
      // set the button's text
      event.target.innerHTML = inputs[i].dataset.warn;
      break;
    }
  }
});
// 'mouseout' event handler
addToCartBtn.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
  event.target.innerHTML = event.target.dataset.title;
  event.target.title = event.target.dataset.title;
});
```

```css
 .form-field {
   margin: 20px;
 }
 
 #add-to-cart-button {
   font-size: 18px;
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<form action="#" name="add-to-cart-form">
  <div class="form-field">
    <label>
      <span>Select Size:</span>
      <select name="item-size" data-warn="Please choose a size" required>
        <option value="">Choose a size</option>
        <option value="s">Small</option>
        <option value="m">Medium</option>
        <option value="l">Large</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
    <label>
      <span>Select Colour:</span>
      <select name="item-colour" data-warn="Please choose a colour" required>
        <option value="">Choose a colour</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
      <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart-button" id="add-to-cart-button" title="Add to Basket" data-title="Add to Cart">Add to Basket</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the CSS part of how you can get the result

```
    .textSwap::before {
        content: "Add to Cart";
    }
    .textSwap:hover::before {
        content: "Please Select";
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style>
.textSwap
{
min-width:200px;
}
    .textSwap::before {
        content: "Add to Cart";
    }
    .textSwap:hover::before {
        content: "Please Select";
    }
    </style>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg textSwap"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to change the text on hover. You could do something like this;

```css
#cart-btn {
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
#cart-btn:after{
  content:'ADD TO BAG';
}
#cart-btn:hover:after{
  content:'PLEASE SELECT SIZE';
}
```

```html
<button id="cart-btn" type="button"></button>
```

Comment: thx for the feedback. But what is if the customer has selected something? Then it should stay to "Add to cart", because they made the decision